# How to center a caption in Table* spanning multiple columns using \parbox?

Tags: tables, captions, parbox

I have two tables that must be placed side by side and spanning both columns of an article. To do so, I've written the following code:

```
\begin{table*}[!ht] 
    \parbox{.40\linewidth}{
        \hfill{}
        \caption{\label{table:accuracy} Accuracy of the Neural Networks} 
        \hfill{}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
            TABLE CONTENT HERE
        \end{tabular}

    }
    \hfill{}
    \parbox{.38\linewidth}{
        \caption{Architecture of the Slim NN and parameters count\label{table:model}}
        \hfill{}
        \begin{tabular}{lcc}
            TABLE CONTENT

        \end{tabular}
        \hfill{}
    }
\end{table*}
```

However, when compiled I have the undesired behavior of having the caption of the first table aligned to left (see picture), while I would like to have it centered to the center of the table[image]

I tried most of the solutions provided in this community like using `\centering` or `\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}` but nothing

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please note that providing a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) usually helps us to help you!

Comment: from your image it looks to me like the caption _is_ centred in the parbox  but that the tabular is over-full, it looks like it is much more than 0.4\linewidth to me.  If you get overfull box warnings ask about _that_ and provide a test file that reproduces the problem

Comment: Off-topic: The placement specifier `[!ht]` has absolutely no effect on the placement of `table*` and `figure*` environments.

Comment: Please also tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: Solved. As suggested by @David Carlisle, whom I thank, it was indeed an overfull box problem. By extending it to 0.65\linewidth I have the correct alignment

Comment: @CampanIgnis your review comment seems rather strange. There was no answer to accept.